# Can i change the values of parameters i pass from view to template in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a parameter in django view and i am passing it to template, now i need to change the value of this variable based on a condition. Is there a way to do this?

Following is my view:-

```
def view_1(request):
    context={'a'=5,'b'=6}
    response=render(request,'abc.html',context)
```

Following is my template(abc.html):-

```
<div>{% if a == 4 %} b==6 {% endif %}</div>
```

I wanted to assign the value 4 to a when b is 6.

Comment: For future reference, you'll receive better answers if you show your actual code in your questions. Not only are there multiple issues with the code you've shared, from your comment on my answer below, it doesn't even accurately represent the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you *can* do this in your template, this kind of processing is best done in the view:

```
def view_1(request):
    context = {'a': 5, 'b': 6}
    if context['a'] == 4:
       context['b'] = 6
    return render(request, 'abc.html', context)
```

Comment: actually i am fetching one value from the backend db and filtering based on that, so it is not possible to do this in view

Comment: That's just not correct. If the context variable is being sent to the template, it most definitely can be modified in the view...Share your actual code, if you're still having issues

Comment: how does your value get from the backend into the template without passing through a view then?